# Javascript alert not working for a particular function

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I  am passing a table with a button in drupal 7 and trying to print the values but iam not getting any alert

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#edit-title-poc').change(function() {
    alert('sdsd'); //**this alert works** 
    var poc_valueasdasd = $("#edit-title-poc option").filter(":selected").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'ajaxpocsdas3',
      data: {
        pocdasd: poc_valueasdasd
      },
      success: function(aasdsabc) {
        //data: value returned from server
        $('#msg-diasdsadsad').html(aasdsabc);
      }
    });
  });

  $('#poc3modulepdf-generator').click(function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called."); //this alert is not working
  });
});
```

This is the screen shot

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements

Comment: whether the element `poc3modulepdf-generator` is added by `$('#msg-diasdsadsad').html(aasdsabc);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: can you post your html code?

Comment: You need to also specifiy the `name` of the button as well as the `id`

Comment: $('#poc3modulepdf-generator').on('click', function(e) {
  alert("Handler for .click() called."); 
});

Comment: Either move `$('#poc3modulepdf-generator').click` into the success callback or use event delegation.

Comment: @M.Nabeel `$('#poc3modulepdf-generator').on('click',` and `('#poc3modulepdf-generator').click(` are equivalent. So this won't solve the problem.

Comment: @t.niese  thanks ..it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$(document).on('click','#poc3modulepdf-generator',function(){
    alert('clicked')
})
```

The reason why your code is not working is because you are binding an event to the element which is not yet created.

Using $(document).on('click','#poc3modulepdf-generator') will bind the event to document. This is event delegation. For more details on event delegation [see here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

I hope this will help.

Comment: When writing an answer you have to explain why this will work and why it won't work with the code of the OP.